# How to find point on Path from the closest point?

Tags: c#, wpf

user128300 has a wonderful solution for this at
[Get point on a path or polyline which is closest to a disconnected point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900642/get-point-on-a-path-or-polyline-which-is-closest-to-a-disconnected-point)
but I cannot seem to get it right when using margins to position the point.

### Xaml code

```
<Style x:Key="Test_Path_Actual" TargetType="Path">
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Blue"/>
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="StrokeLineJoin" Value="Round"/>
    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill"/>
    <Setter Property="Data" Value="M 0,20 L 30 0 L 60,20 L 30,40 Z"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type c:ConnectorStrip}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type c:ConnectorStrip}">
                <Grid x:Name="PART_Grid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Path x:Name="PART_PathActual" Style="{StaticResource Test_Path_Actual}"/>
                    <Path x:Name="PART_PathHitArea" Style="{StaticResource Test_Path_Hit_Area}"/>
                    <s:ConnectorSeeker x:Name="PART_ConnectorSeeker" Visibility="collapsed"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

### C# code

```
    void hitPath_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ScaleX = this.DesiredSize.Width / origWidth;
        ScaleY = this.DesiredSize.Height / origHeight;

        ConnectorSeeker connSeekerL = GetConnectorSeeker();
        Point pt = GetClosestPointOnPath(e.GetPosition(this), actualPath.Data);

        if (connSeekerL != null)
        {
            double marginLeft = pt.X - (connSeekerL.Width / 2);
            double marginTop = pt.Y - (connSeekerL.Height / 2);
            double marginRight = this.DesiredSize.Width - pt.X - (connSeekerL.Width / 2);
            double marginBottom = this.DesiredSize.Height - pt.Y - (connSeekerL.Height / 2);

            connSeekerL.Margin = new Thickness(marginLeft, marginTop, marginRight, marginBottom);
            connSeekerL.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot find connector seeker");
        }
    }
```

The margin positioning logic works fine when e.GetPosition(this) for the current cursor position is used but I want that point on the nearest Path.

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

Simply replace `this.DesiredSize.Width` with `this.ActualWidth` and `this.DesiredSize.Height` with `this.ActualHeight`.

The reason is if your Path object (Or the container of your Path object) is smaller than the parent, `this.DesiredSize` will be smaller than the actual size which causes problems with margin positioning.